# Error: could not handle the request with Google Cloud Function and Express

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-functions

this is my code. Why when I go to the url of my cloud function I receive this message :"Error: could not handle the request" and I didn't see "Hello World!" ? Thanks

```
exports.simple = (req,res) => {

var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

module.exports = app;

return app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send("Hello World!"))
    .then((result) => {
     console.log("DONE",result);
     console.log("Delete opportunity");
    })
     .catch((err) => {
      console.log("ERROR",err);
    }) 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work by placing all the code outside the default entry point and by setting the `app` variable as the new entry point.

[image]