# App is not defined in google cloud function with express

Tags: javascript, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use google cloud function to make some API calls. When I deploy on google function, the site send me an Error : `Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file app.js can't be loaded. Is there a syntax error in your code? Detailed stack trace: ReferenceError: app is not defined`

What could be the reason for this?

These are the files:

```
//app.js

exports.simple = app;
```

App.js should call the google cloud function that execute the function call "simple" 
IMAGE : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKiO0.png)

```
// server.js

// BASE SETUP
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
const port  = 8080;

// ROUTES
var router = express.Router(); // get an instance of router
router.use(function(req, res, next) { // route middleware that will happen on every request
 console.log(req.method, req.url); // log each request to the console
 next(); // continue doing what we were doing and go to the route
});

app.use('/',require ('./Routers/API/home'));

app.use('/leads',require ('./Routers/API/leads'));

app.use('/people',require ('./Routers/API/people'));

app.use('/companies',require ('./Routers/API/companies'));

app.use('/opportunities',require ('./Routers/API/opportunities'));

app.use('/projects',require ('./Routers/API/projects'));

app.use('/tasks',require ('./Routers/API/tasks'));

app.use('/activities',require ('./Routers/API/activities'));

app.use('/', router); // apply the routes to our application


// START THE SERVER
// ==============================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening ' + port);

module.exports = {app};
```

Comment: Cloud Functions will not allow you to use `app.listen()`.  For HTTP type functions, the infrastructure will be listening for you.  You just provide the app the handling the incoming connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mentioned on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57592171/11765092), to use express in a Google Cloud Function, you can put your server code inside the main file and set the `app` variable as the entry point.